How \pgfpointxyz plots a point in 2d?
When I instruct PGF to plot a point in the 3d space with \pgfpointxyz, how PGF projects this point on the 2D canvas?
Inside the file pgfcorepoints.code.tex the definition of \pgfpointxyz says that
\global\pgf@x=\pgftemp@x\pgf@xx%
  \global\advance\pgf@x by \pgftemp@y\pgf@yx%
  \global\advance\pgf@x by \pgftemp@z\pgf@zx%

from which I understand that the projection matrix used is

But I couldn't find any numerical value assigned to the TeX dimensions that comprise the matrix elements. Can anyone refer me to the values they take?
Can anyone tell me if the math I presented here is correct at all?
A MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfsetarrowsend{to}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{1}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{0}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{0}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}

\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{1}
%\makeatletter
%\show\pgf@x %%\pgf@x is stored in \dimen145
%\showthe\dimen145
%\show\pgf@y %%\pgf@x is stored in \dimen145
%\showthe\dimen146
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}

